# Find result from joining a table in rails :conditions part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, join, ruby-on-rails-2

Currently the attachments are searched based on `attachment_file_name`, `tags` and `employee_id`, I would like to search based on Employee name as well, how can I go with it?
Two models must be used.

1. **Employee** - which has name of employee
2. **LessonplanAttachment** - contains the id of the employee.

The code part.

```
def search_ajax
   @attachments = LessonplanAttachment.find(:all,
    :conditions => ["attachment_file_name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR employee_id = ?",
      "#{params[:query]}%","#{params[:query]}%",params[:query]])
end
```

Comment: Can you confirm what version of rails you are using if you are getting undefined method `joins` for your class?

Comment: rails 2, using rvm 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
LessonplanAttachment.joins("JOIN employee on employee_id").find(:all, :conditions =>
  ["attachment_file_name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR employee_id = ? OR employee.name = ?",
  "#{params[:query]}%","#{params[:query]}%",params[:query], params[:query]]
```

Comment: undefined method `joins'

Comment: is LessonplanAttachment a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the following association in your LessonplanAttachment model.

```
belongs_to :employee
```

Now you can change your code as per the following

```
@attachments = LessonplanAttachment.joins([:employee]).where("attachment_file_name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR employee_id = ? OR employees.name LIKE ?", "#{params[:query]}%","#{params[:query]}%",params[:query],"#{params[:query]}%")
```

Comment: undefined method `joins'

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have an association `belongs_to :employee` on your `LessonplanAttachment` class, for rails 2, you can add a `:joins` attribute to the options on `find`. Something like this should work:

```
@attachments = LessonplanAttachment.find(:all,
 :joins => :employee,
 :conditions => [
   "attachment_file_name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR 
    employee_id = ? OR employees.name LIKE ?",
   "#{params[:query]}%","#{params[:query]}%",params[:query],"#{params[:query]}%"])
```